# C++ Winapi HWND Get WndProc configuration

Tags: c++, winapi, wndproc, hwnd

I need to get the current `WndProc` with its messages and configuration and add my own code to it. Why do I need this? Because I'm working under an IDE that defines a window (and its children controls) with a `WndProc`, and I need to modify it because It contains all the actions related with every control. If I point a control to a custom `WndProc` the control loses all the actions and configuration set by the IDE. Suggestions?

Scheme:

```
HWND button; //My Button
LONG_PTR wndProc = GetWindowLongPtr(button, GWL_WNDPROC); //Getting the WndProc

wndProc -> Get this `WndProc` source code

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){

    wndProc (all the data);
    + my messages

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get source code of "old" WndProc of course, but you can call it using CallWindowProc() in your new wnd proc. Check out this article:

[When you subclass a window, it's the original window procedure of the window you subclass you have to call when you want to call the original window procedure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/05/07/9592397.aspx)

Quote:

> ... your subclass function should go something like this:
>
> ```
> wndProcOrig = 
>     (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hwndButton, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)SubclassWndProc);  
>
> LRESULT CALLBACK SubclassWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
> {
>    switch (wm) {
>    ...
>    default:
>        return CallWindowProc(wndprocOrig, hwnd, wm, wParam, lParam);
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: Your answer should ideally include the relevant information, even though The Old New Thing probably isn't going away any time soon.

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: You should use [`SetWindowSubClass()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx) instead of `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_WNDPROC)`. See this article on the same blog: [Safer subclassing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/11/55653.aspx)

Comment: Official documentation on [Subclassing Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx).